# Is it possible migrate existing programs installed in windows?

Tags: wine, playonlinux

Can I move my already installed programs to my ubuntu installation, and if so can someone give me the general gist of it? I'm pretty good with a computer so if you give me the general outline I should be able to manage.

Answer (score 1):

For those that are interested I found some workarounds.

Alot of programs will work without installs. Just use playonlinux to install the program you're trying to move and after it sets up the virtual drive you can just move it and make a shortcut to the exe for your program.

For others that are registry specific you can find the reg entries via good and add them yourself. Ive gotten almost all of my programs working now. :D

Answer (score 0):

Regret not. The Windows 8 Registry will prevent those apps from working, as it will see files are not where they should be and will also recognize the changes.